# Delphi XE7: Debug points not appearing, Breakpoints not getting hit on debugging and CPU window opens up

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide, breakpoints, delphi-xe7

On building my code i cannot see the debug points in the pages.Only the page which is open while building shows the debug points.Also, The breakpoint is not getting hit and CPU window is opening by default where debug is set. I searched for the same and found this following statement on Embarcadero page (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/CPU_Windows_Index):

> The CPU window also opens automatically whenever program execution stops at a location for which source code is unavailable. For example, the debugger cannot open the source file if you link a DLL (Windows) built with debug information but do not include its source file in your project, or if you place the source file in a directory not specified in your project.

I also tried following things:

- When I create a new project, put a breakpoint, it hits (no CPU
  window opens up in this case).
- When I modify the original code (like    just put `ShowMessage('Hello World');`) where debug point is not
  hitting, message dialog appears but debug is not hitting.
- I
  uninstalled and installed XE7 again, but problem persists.
- Tried
  cleaning the project, but did not work.

Please help me in fixing this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basics: Have you have compiled your program with debug information?

Comment: @MartynA.. There is only one copy of the project source files.

Comment: @dummzeuch.. Yes I have tried compiling in debug mode and then building it, still no change.

Comment: It seems the problem is due to some windows 10 update..  my colleague is seeing the same issue now after installing the windows 10 update

Answer (score 2):

As i also had a lot of problems with getting my debugger to work, so i made myself a list of what has to be checked. So here are some things you could try:

- use the "debug" buildconfiguration of your project, which should be configured like this

  - searchpath matches your actual sources
  - "local symbols" is true
  - "with debug dcus" is true
  - "debug-information" is debug-information
  - "optimization" is false
  - one time i also had to check "remote debugging symbols"
- try to close the ide and reopen it with just one project
- if you use devextension, go to devextensions options

  - under compilation -> check "release compiler unit cache of other projects before compiling"
  - under extended ide settings -> check "disable package cache"
- in delphi options under "debugger options", "integrated debugging" has to be true
  (but sometimes it helps to uncheck this, close the ide, reopen and check again)

I hope, this also helps you